# How to clean up blazor server project

Tags: c#, blazor, blazor-server-side

I am new to blazor and I've chosen to learn blazorserver but whenever i create a project, it comes along shipped with a lot of stuff i don't need. I don't need the layout it offers. I want to build my own layout from scratch. I also want to get rid of bootstrap and replace it with tailwind. The problem is that there are a lot of files and directories that make me fear to break the app. Is there a kinda command that can generate a much cleaner project or some way of manually cleaning it app without breaking the app. I appreciate any help.

Comment: Not from Microsoft. There is a fully clean project, but then you should know what to add. You should use something like git for version management and just start deleting stuff. That way you can always go back to the previous state. You'll learn a lot that way. You could also try to compare the webassembly blazor template with the server side.  The webasm has things separated in server and client side.

Comment: Security is very important to me and that's why i chose to learn blazorserver. Would you refer me to a page where i can get these git commands.

Comment: That's easy to Google. And most IDEs nowadays have build in version management, often based on git. (Note this is not a forum, please read the stack overflow guidelines)

Comment: It's an impossible question to answer because nobody knows what you want to remove and what you want to keep but you.  Stripping out the base template will be a good learning exercise!  I can give you the ultimate basic project but that would almost certainly not contain things that you need - see https://github.com/ShaunCurtis/Blazr.Skinny

Comment: Chris Sainty just did a talk on Blazor with Tailwind (on Youtube). He also has a great book on the topic. https://chrissainty.com/adding-tailwind-css-v3-to-a-blazor-app/

Answer (score 0):

If you are afraid of breaking the app by deleting something then it's better to keep it. You already figured out that you can replace bootstrap library with tailwind and that you can replace the layout with your own. While developing on the project you will start understanding what is the purpose of each folder or file in the starter template. After you understand their purpose, you will be able to decide if you need them or not.

Also learning how to use version control (e.g. git), like @JHBonarius mentioned, is very good advice. So when you break something you can easily revert back to previous working version of code.